# Bot Framework Composer - Local Certificate Issue Error

Tags: botframework, bot-framework-composer

I am having an issue with the tool. This has been an issue even in the emulator and I think it's the same issue with this error.

Could not load component list:Error https://schemas.botframework.com/schemas/component/v1.0/component.schema: unable to get local issuer certificate Error Microsoft.QnAMakerDialog: Cannot extend component because it is not included Error Microsoft.QnAMakerDialog: Cannot set property 'const' of undefined *** Could not merge components ***

I honestly don't have any knowledge on the issuer certificate, I have done some googling already and not of them is helping.

[image]